# Cannot read property 'myOperation' found in wsdl - issue while using NodeJs and soap client

Tags: node.js, soap, npm, wsdl, node-soap

In few words, there are around 100 soap web services and I need to expose them as rest via NodeJs. I mean, for each soap service there will a single rest service playing the role of a facade.

I install "npm install soap" as explained in https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap and https://github.com/23/node-soap. The example below is working properly so I understand the installation is fine.

So, my strach question is: how can I read the wsdl below? Kindly, see how I am trying by following the success example and I am getting certain error which seems I am missing some extra word in "client.CadastroService.CadastroServiceSoapBinding.consultarDados". Well, the wdls from such example has a small difference from my wsdl. The example relies on "wsdl:input wsaw:Action=..." and mine doesn't use wsaw:Action at all. I guess it doesn't change the way I have to call it. I am calling following this pattern: "wsdl:service name"."wsdl:binding name"."wsdl:message name"

Example working:

```
var soap = require('soap');

var url = "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl";

var args = {"tns:request":"GOOG"};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
 client.CadastroService.BasicHttpBinding_IStockQuoteService.GetStockQuote(args, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```

My wsdl (obviously edited to make simpler):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://service.ws.mycompany.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="CadastroService" targetNamespace="http://service.ws.mycompany.com/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://service.ws.mycompany.com/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://service.ws.mycompany.com/" version="1.0">


  <xs:element name="consultarDados" type="tns:consultarDados"/>

  <xs:element name="root" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>


  <xs:complexType name="basicResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codigoRetorno" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mensagemRetorno" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="consultarDados">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="tns:ConsultarInput"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ConsultarInput">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numCartao" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="consultarDadosResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:ConsultarResponse"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ConsultarResponse">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:basicResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="blockCode" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="blockCode2" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codBloqueioBoletimProtecao" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codLogo" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codMotivoEmissao2via" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codProdutoDN" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataAberturaConta" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataCancelamento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataEmissaoCartao" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataExclusaoBoletimProtecao" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataExpiracaoConta" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataGeracaoPlastico" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataInclusaoBoletimProtecao" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataInicioAtraso" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataNascimento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataProximoCorte" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataProximoVencto" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataUltimaAlteracaoLimite" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataUltimaAlteracaoVencto" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataUltimoPagamento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataValidadePlastico" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataVenctoPenultimaFatura" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dataVenctoUltFatura" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dddCelular1" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dddCelular2" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dddComercial" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dddResidencial" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ddiCelular1" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ddiCelular2" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ddiComercial" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ddiResidencial" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="descTipoPessoa" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="diaCorteAtual" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="diaVencimento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="endereco" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enderecoBairro" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enderecoCEP" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enderecoCidade" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enderecoComplemento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enderecoNumero" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enderecoUF" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="estadoCivilDesc" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="flagTipoFaturamento" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indClienteVip" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indClienteVipDesc" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indDebitoAutomatico" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indEstadoCivil" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indLimiteSegregado" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indSexo" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indicadorCartaoBloqueado" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indicadorCartaoOuConta" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indicadorCompraParcelada" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indicadorContato" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="indicadorTeleSaque" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nomeMae" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nomeOrg" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nomePai" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nomePortator" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numCartaoAnterior" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numCartaoTitular" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numCelular1" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numCelular2" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numChpras" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numComercial" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numConta" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numCpfCnpj" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numOrg" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numRG" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numResidencial" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="qtdAdicionais" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="qtdCompraParceladaAtual" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element name="qtdDiasAtrasoUltimaFatura" type="xs:int"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="qtdVezesFaturamentoConta" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="saldoAFaturar" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="saldoAntepenultimaFatura" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="saldoCompraInter" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="saldoFaturaFechada" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="saldoInterFatura" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="saldoInterUltimaFaturaFechada" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sexoDesc" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="situacaoConta" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="situacaoContaDesc" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="taxaCashProxPeriodo" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="taxaJurosProxPeriodo" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipoCartao" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipoPessoa" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipoPortador" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipoPortadorDesc" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="totalCashAFaturar" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorAtraso" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteCash" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteCashInter" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteCredito" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteCreditoInter" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteDispCash" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteDispCashInter" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteDispCredito" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteDispCreditoInter" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteParcDisponivelSegregado" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorLimiteParcTotalSegregado" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorPagtoMinimoUltFatura" type="xs:double"/>
          <xs:element name="valorUltimoPagamento" type="xs:double"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>


</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="consultarDados">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:consultarDados" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="Cadastro">

    <wsdl:operation name="consultarDados">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:consultarDados" name="consultarDados">
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:consultarDadosResponse" name="consultarDadosResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>

  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="CadastroServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:Cadastro">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

    <wsdl:operation name="consultarDados">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="consultarDados">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="consultarDadosResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CadastroService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:CadastroServiceSoapBinding" name="CadastroPort">
      <soap:address location="http://myip...:myport/ws-myapp/cadastro"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Entire error:

```
demetrio@nodejs ~/dev/NodeJsSrc $ node consultaDados.js 
/home/demetrio/dev/NodeJsSrc/consultaDados.js:9
    client.CadastroService.CadastroServiceSoapBinding.consultarDados(args, function(err, result){
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'consultarDados' of undefined
    at /home/demetrio/dev/NodeJsSrc/consultaDados.js:9:54
    at /home/demetrio/node_modules/soap/lib/soap.js:58:5
    at null.callback (/home/demetrio/node_modules/soap/lib/soap.js:25:9)
    at /home/demetrio/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1073:12
    at WSDL._processNextInclude (/home/demetrio/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1148:12)
    at WSDL.processIncludes (/home/demetrio/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1191:8)
    at /home/demetrio/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1028:10
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
demetrio@nodejs ~/dev/NodeJsSrc $
```

How I am trying to read the soap web service (I basically followed the above example working)

```
var soap = require('soap');

var url = "http://myIp...:myPort/ws-myApp/cadastro?wsdl";

var args = {"tns:request":"GOOG"};

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){

    client.CadastroService.CadastroServiceSoapBinding.consultarDados(args, function(err, result){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
    });
});
```